# Python loop through list of symbols for API request

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

Kind, smart people:   Please help me - I've been working on this for a week now and just can't figure it out.   I'm trying to read a list (text file called testsymbol.txt) that contains 8 stock symbols, then take each one and make an API request for some historical data.   I take the API response and use Pandas to save as a .csv file.

The script works for the first symbol, but I can't understand how to make it loop and pick back up with the second symbol, third, etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is what I've tried:

> f = open(r"c:\pytest\testsymbol.txt", 'r')
>
> with f:
> var1 = [line.strip() for line in f]
> length = len(var1)
> i = 0
>
> TSymbol = var1
>
> from twelvedata import TDClient
> import pandas as pd
> import requests
> import csv
> import os
>
> td = TDClient(apikey='xxxxxxx')
>
> ts = td.time_series(
> symbol=(TSymbol[i]),
> interval="5min",
> outputsize=5,
> timezone="America/New_York",
> start_date="2022-10-03 9:30:00",
> end_date="2022-12-30 4:30:00",
> )
>
> x = ts.as_json()
>
> > 
>
> df = pd.DataFrame (x, columns = ['datetime', 'open', 'high',
> 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
> df.flags.allows_duplicate_labels = False
>
> df.insert(0, column = 'Symbol',  value=(TSymbol[i]))
> df.assign(Symbol = TSymbol[i])
>
> df[['date', 'time']] = df['datetime'].str.split(" ", expand = True)
> df.pop('datetime')
>
> df.loc[:,['Symbol', 'date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']]
>
> df = df[['Symbol', 'date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']]
>
> testpath=("C:\PyTest\Oct2022\")
>
> df.to_csv(f'{testpath}{TSymbol[i]}.csv', index = False, header = True)

#Where to go next?

Comment: Between `td = ` and `ts = td.time_series`, you should just need to add the following line: `for i in TSymbol:` then indent the rest (providing that `TSymbol` is indeed a list).

Comment: Yes, TSymbol is a list.   When printed it is:  ['A', 'AA', 'AAL', 'AAPL', 'ABBV', 'ABNB', 'ABT', ''].   I tried your suggestion and am still getting just one output csv file, (A.csv).  Do I need to increment to next i in TSymbol?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  You should instead use `for i in range(len(TSymbol)):`, as it is a list and requires indexing from 0 to the length of the list).  That should work.

Comment: That didn't work - I got a syntax error when it gets to "symbol=(TSymbol[i])".  I think there's got to be some mapping between my variable name TSymbol which is just the list of strings, and the API's required field "Symbol".    I can't just figure out how to do that.  Is there some special syntax to make an API parameter (is that even the right word?) equal to a variable that you can iterate over?   Is it because I need to convert my variable to something in JSON?

Comment: That should probably be `symbol=TSymbol[i]`, without the parentheses.